# How i can set non www in google search mobile

Tags: url, mobile, joomla, dns, web

I want to change my domain from https://www.example.com into https://example.com, i've done it through google webmaster tools and the way it has been successful in desktop google search, but did not succeed in the mobile google search. 
I also have to change it through the .htaccess file, but it still does not work, what should I do

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with .htaccess, you have to be careful to also handle sub-directories and parameters. Try this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

That should correctly direct any www page you visit to the equivalent non-www version.

**EDIT**

To have Google showcase your non-www version instead of your www version, you need to submit the non-www link to Google through [this link](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url). It takes Google a while to update changes, so be patient. If their desktop version shows the update and the mobile version does not, the chances are that those are two separate 'actions' for Google caches, and you simply need to wait for the second one.

For what it's worth, if you redirect users to the non-www site through .htaccess anyway, it won't **matter** if Google shows the www URL -- as soon as a visitor attempts to visit your www site, they will automatically get redirected to the non-www site.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Define "*doesn't work*". That .htaccess code redirect any URL that is typed in as `www.example.com/link` to `https://example.com/link`. Is that not what you wanted? If not, please edit your question to clearly describe the problem and desired solution.

Comment: Yes, i want change my URL into https://example.com, but the code that you give me is still not work...
It's still appear https://www.example.com in mobile google search...
Do you still any option..?

Comment: Ohh, *Google Search* caches. You're not actually trying to redirect users who visit your www site to a non-www site. I've updated my answer to cover this.

Comment: Awesome :) If my answer solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. Doing so means the question doesn't get stuck on the 'Unanswered' queue, and also awards rep to both the question asker and answerer :)